# Is there any REST service available in Salesforce to Convert Leads into Accounts?

Tags: salesforce

We have to convert Leads to accounts via REST -OAuth calls. We are able to create, update(Edit) and Detail Lead fields but not able to convert them.

We found the same is possible via SOAP API but we are following REST OAuth only.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes and we resolved this by creating an Apex class for REST call. Sample code is this -

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Lead/*')
global with sharing class RestLeadConvert {            

    @HttpGet
    global static String doGet() {
        String ret = 'fail';
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String leadId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);              
        Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
        lc.setLeadId(leadId);

        LeadStatus convertStatus = [SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true LIMIT 1];
        lc.setConvertedStatus(convertStatus.MasterLabel);           
        Database.LeadConvertResult lcr ;
        try{
            lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
            system.debug('*****lcr.isSuccess()'+lcr.isSuccess());            
            ret = 'ok';
        }
        catch(exception ex){
            system.debug('***NOT CONVERTED**');           
        }
        return ret;
    }   
}
```

And you can use this call by

```
<Your Instance URL>/services/apexrest/Lead/<LeadId>
```

This test will give you around 93% of coverage.

```
@isTest
public class RestLeadConvertTest{

    static testMethod void testHttpGet() {
        Lead l = new Lead();
        l.FirstName = 'First';
        l.LastName = 'Last';
        l.Company = 'Unit Test';
        insert l;

        Test.startTest();
        RestRequest req = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse res = new RestResponse();
        req.requestURI = '/Lead/' + l.Id;
        req.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = req;
        RestContext.response= res;
        RestLeadConvert.doGet();
        Test.stopTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: Would this work for connected apps as well? As in, if my app server is on AWS/GCE?

Comment: Thanks a lot for posting this. Since salesforce requires unit test coverage in order to deploy code, could you please post your unit test for this code? I'm sure it would help folks out.

Comment: Brilliant - this was super helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a one-off SOAP request to convert a lead and use the same OAuth token that you already have for the REST API.

The request body should look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ens="urn:sobject.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:fns="urn:fault.partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:tns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soap:Header>
      <tns:SessionHeader>
         <sessionId>YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN</sessionId>
      </tns:SessionHeader>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <tns:convertLead>
         <tns:leadConverts>
            <tns:leadId>YOUR_LEAD_ID</tns:leadId>
            <tns:convertedStatus>Closed - Converted</tns:convertedStatus>
         </tns:leadConverts>
      </tns:convertLead>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

```
curl -H 'SOAPAction: null' -H 'Content-Type: text/xml' --data BODY_FROM_ABOVE https://your-instance-url/services/Soap/u/52.0
```

Note that the `SOAPAction` header is required, even though Salesforce does not use it.

The result will be returned as XML similar to:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <LimitInfoHeader>
         <limitInfo>
            <current>91</current>
            <limit>15000</limit>
            <type>API REQUESTS</type>
         </limitInfo>
      </LimitInfoHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <convertLeadResponse>
         <result>
            <accountId>0015x00002C95kMAAR</accountId>
            <contactId>0035x00003NjdeyAAB</contactId>
            <leadId>00Q5x00001tHg1tEAC</leadId>
            <opportunityId>0065x000025fDsWAAU</opportunityId>
            <success>true</success>
         </result>
      </convertLeadResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

If you are more comfortable with JSON than XML, OneGraph provides a GraphQL API that wraps the convertLead functionality.

It's best to create your own OneGraph app to get a custom app_id, but one is provided here for demonstration purposes.

The GraphQL query will be:

```
mutation ConvertLead {
  salesforce(
    auths: {
      salesforceOAuth: {
        instanceUrl: "YOUR_INSTANCE_URL"
        token: "YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN"
      }
    }
  ) {
    convertLead(
      input: { leadConverts: [{ leadId: "YOUR_LEAD_ID" }] }
    ) {
      leadConverts {
        lead {
          id
          name
        }
        account {
          name
          id
        }
        contact {
          name
          id
        }
        opportunity {
          name
          id
        }
        success
        errors {
          message
          statusCode
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then the request will look like:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'https://serve.onegraph.com/graphql?app_id=4687c59d-8f9c-494a-ab67-896fd706cee9' --data '{"query": "QUERY_FROM_ABOVE"}'
```

The result will be returned as JSON that looks like:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "salesforce": {
      "convertLead": {
        "leadConverts": [
          {
            "lead": {
              "id": "00Q5x00001tHg1tEAC",
              "name": "Daniel Boone"
            },
            "account": {
              "name": "Company",
              "id": "0015x00002C95kMAAR"
            },
            "contact": {
              "name": "Daniel Boone",
              "id": "0035x00003NjdeyAAB"
            },
            "opportunity": {
              "name": "New Opportunity",
              "id": "0065x000025fDsWAAU"
            },
            "relatedPersonAccountId": null,
            "success": true,
            "errors": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```