# PHP: Is there any SOAP service available in Salesforce to Convert Leads into opportunity and Account?

Tags: php, soap, salesforce, lead

I have to convert Leads to accounts and opportunity via SOAP calls. 
I am able to create, update(Edit) and Detail Lead fields but not able to convert them.

I am using PHP Scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Qazi I hope, link below will solve your problem.
[PHP Soap API: For salesforce SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit_20.0_ConvertLead_Sample_(Enterprise))

Comment: is their any way by doing it using rest api  @fazalerabbi
i had tried it in many ways but not able to do it. how to use convertlead in rest api

Comment: I haven't try REST API, may be this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663119/is-there-any-rest-service-available-in-saleforce-to-convert-leads-into-accounts